# Select element in nicEdit

Tags: javascript, nicedit

I'm developing a **nicEdit** plugin to upload files other than images. To do that I took the nicUpload plugin and I'm adapting it.

As you can see in the code below I first insert an image and then I try to wrap that image in a link, but it didn't work.

If I remove the `//Insert the image` section I'm able to wrap the selected text, but I want to create the image and then select that image as the text to wrap.

The `//Insert the link` section is not working at all when the `//Insert the image` section is present.

```
onUploaded:function(B){
        this.removePane();
        // Insert the image.
        if(!this.im) {
            var tmp = 'javascript:nicImTemp();';
            this.ne.nicCommand("insertImage",tmp);
            this.im = this.findElm('IMG','src',tmp);
        }
        if(this.im) {
            this.im.setAttributes({
                src : 'http://127.0.0.1/nicEditDev/src/nicFile/images/pdf.png',
                alt : 'PDF'
            });
        }
        // Insert the link wrapping the image.
        console.log(this.im);
        var url=B.links.original;
        if(!this.ln) {
            var tmp = 'javascript:nicTemp();';
            this.ne.nicCommand("createlink",tmp);
            this.ln = this.findElm('A','href',tmp);
        }
        if(this.ln) {
            this.ln.setAttributes({
                href : url,
                title : 'PDF',
                innerHTML : this.im
            }); 
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

`onUploaded: function(a) {
        this.removePane();
        var c = a.url;
        if (this.im) {
            this.im || (this.ne.selectedInstance.restoreRng(),
            this.ne.nicCommand("insertImage", c),
            this.im = this.findElm("IMG", "src", c));
            var b = parseInt(this.ne.selectedInstance.elm.getStyle("width"));
            this.im && this.im.setAttributes({
                src: c,
                width: b && a.width ? Math.min(b, a.width) : "",
                alt: a.alt
            })
        } 
        else {
            this.ln || (this.ne.selectedInstance.restoreRng(),
            this.ne.nicCommand("createlink", c),
            this.ln = this.findElm('A', 'href', c));
            this.ln && this.ln.setAttributes({
                href: c,
                title: 'PDF'
            });
        }
    }`